# RegEx to convert files from LUA to JSON

Tags: c#, json, regex, lua

There we go again. RegEx. The most mysterious thing on this planet.

I have lots of LUA tables as .lua files

```
local tbl = {
   SomeObject = {
      Key = "Value",
      AnotherKey = {
         Key1 = "Value 1",
         Key2 = "Value 2",
         Key3 = "Value 3",
      }
   },
   AnotherObject = {
      Key = "Value",
      AnotherKey = {
         Key1 = "Value 1",
         Key2 = "Value 2",
         Key3 = "Value 3",
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to convert these files to JSON so they can be used more easily across different applications. Is there any fancy RegEx I could use in C# e.g. to convert them?

Comment: You can't. Lua scripts, even when used only for configuration, [are not Regular Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), therefore you cannot parse them using regular-expressions.

Comment: This can't be done (or maybe _could_ via a complete hack) with regular expressions. The best way to convert the code to JSON is to parse the code with an Antlr parser from [the lua grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/lua), then use either a parse tree visitor or a template engine to make the translation. The grammar works fine on your code.

Answer (score 4):

In general: No. RegEx is incapable of parsing Lua since parsing requires a context-free grammar (CFG). At a tokenization level, RegEx might suffice though; the main difference between Lua table constructors *for your example* is that JSON uses `"key": value` whereas Lua uses `["key"] = value` or `key = value` if key is a valid identifier (which seems to be the only case in your example). Replacing `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_])%s=` with `"$1":` where `$1` is the first capture should thus work, assuming you don't have this in your string keys...

I would strongly recommend against using RegEx. The simplest & most reliable way to go about this however is to **execute these files as Lua code, then write the Lua tables to JSON from inside Lua**. Also make sure to sandbox the environment in which you load these files properly.

Comment: "execute these files as Lua code" <-- There are significant logistics and security issues if one were to choose this approach though...

Comment: @Dai logistics? I don't think the OPs input is user-provided, so security shouldn't be that big a concern. The only proper way to turn a program code abused as object notation into data structures unfortunately is to execute it (unless the code is limited to a subset that practically is an object notation, but that's not apparent from the question). The OP can use [Luon](https://github.com/appgurueu/luon) next time ;)

Comment: By "logistics" I meant the possibility of having to keep a working Lua environment around just for the sake of reading a single config file.

Comment: @Dai right, but libraries for C# (I'm thinking the horribly outdated Moonsharp here) exist.